# Was the German soldiers' reaction during the bar shootout realistic?

Tags: plot-explanation, inglourious-basterds

In the Bar Shootout Scene in *Inglourious Basterds*, two things do not match up,

**First**: there is one German officer knowing the bastards are spies, so when the first shot is fired why the Nazi soldiers start shooting the Basterds? how could they tell who is not German or is a spy at the moment (they are all drunk too)?

**Second**: With the fact that all other Nazi soldiers except the officer are way too drunk, they react to the shooting too soon for the fact I mentioned and they shoot with accuracy while being drunk.

So are those possibly directing/writing errors?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Thanx :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be safe to assume that the German soldiers at the tavern were all deployed in the same region and hence knew each other.

First : When first shots are heard the drunk soldiers see that the German officer, who was their senior in rank and who was known to them is being shot at by some strangers who are in uniform but who are not known to them. This is enough for them to get in action and fire on the strangers who shot the Officer. It is also possible that could hear the conversation taking place at that table. Remember that the bar owner is able to hear the conversation. They could have known that the German Officer was interrogating the strangers.

Second : We can't say exactly how drunk they were and how well they could shoot when they were drunk. We don't know how accurate there shots were. may be they fired many times and some shots found the target. Also please note that there wasn't a lot of distance between them so they had to fire at a very close range which should not be difficult for the soldiers.

Comment: And.. 3) I thought was implied the spies were shooting better than the locals in that more than one of them was left alive as opposed to just a single German soldier, whereas they had begun the shootout outnumbered.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i didn't understand what you meant completely , but i oppose to Ankit , our good guys were not drunk so with the advantage knowing that there would be a shootout they should have killed the soldiers with minimum casualty , and you can see they look drunk pay attention to how they talk , and they knew the bartender too , so why they shot him when he pulled out the gun before knowing who he will shoot?(i know the fact that a french bartender would shoot nazis but the fact is still that when you have a couple of drinks , even if its beer your reaction time increases)

Comment: and there is another fact , the german officer was an officer as you say , but the bastards had higher ranks , at least two of them had , so the fact that officer was allowing himself to join them was a mistake too , i would watch the scene again though to confirm what your answer says or deny it

Comment: Yes the bastards showed high ranks, but no one knew them. No one had seen them before and they were immediately under suspicion since first of all a soldier questions their accent and next the German officer tries to interrogate them. So I would say despite the show of high ranks the bastards were under suspicion right from the beginning.

Comment: but anyway lets say the bar scene was not necessary , it's point was just killing the present members not to participate in the rest of the movie , as two of them were German Actors so they Could Speak German Fluently, then the american bastards presence at the bar was unnessecary too , i mean this sean ruined the movie i think , don't you think so?

Comment: I think the story  could have been carried without the bar scene as well, but I must say I enjoyed the bar scene and it acted as an important instrument in the story. Due to the Bar scene Landa was able to identify bastards

Comment: Remember that after the shootout German actress's sandal and her signature on napkin are found by Landa.

Comment: well yess , but i mean some things in the movie where just added to the movie for more complication not improving the story , the fact that shushana gets killed during her plan in the way it occured was not nice , and the fact that bastards shot hitler ending such a devils life quickly rather letting him burn in the fire of his creation , was not nice toward the movie , what i mean is the movie could be more realistic or even more tragic but also a very good one too, consider the valkyries ending , it was tragic but i liked the whole movie in despite of that i don't even like tom cruise,